# How to select multiple servers through parameterized values in Jenkins at time if I need to deploy all servers .?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

```
parameters {
        string (name: 'image_tag', defaultValue: '')
        choice (name:'APP_NAME',choices:['upf_ids','upf_dns','n2iwf_nwu'])
        booleanParam(name:'UPDATE_PIPELINE',defaultValue: true)
        choice (name:'exe_server',choices:['exe15','exe16'])
        
    
    }
    
    stages{

      stage('helm_update'){
            steps{
                dir('helm'){
                    git poll: false,
                        credentialsId:'Bitbucket-credentials',
                        url: 'git@bitbucket.org:exium-c2/gitops.git'
                    script{
                    
                        if (env.exe_server == "exe15"){
                        
                    
                           sshagent(['xedge-vm']) {
                              sh '''
                                  scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no xedge-vm/config/env-exe15  centos@52.14.164.158:/exedge-volume/exedge/env-exe15
                                  ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no centos@52.14.164.158       "cd /exedge-volume/exedge/ && hostname"
                                 '''
                            }  
                        }
                        if (env.exe_server == "exe16"){
                          sshagent(['xedge-vm']){
                            sh '''
                        
                                scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no   xedge-vm/config/env-exe16    centos@54.145.46.212:/exedge-volume/exedge/env-exe16
                                ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no   centos@54.145.46.212       "cd /exedge-volume/exedge && hostname"
                              '''
                        
                          }
                     
                        }        
                    }
                }
        
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

''
I have added multiple servers in jenkins pipeline so i have written a if condition  to select at a time one server to deploy but I need how to select multiple servers at time if I need to deploy.
''

Comment: Could someone please help in the above issue..?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is supported by Active Choice Parameter Plugin, check here for more details https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/